# What are the new features in Eclipse Galileo?

Tags: java, eclipse

I  couldn't find any description of this on the site.

What are some of the new features/improvements/changes in Eclipse Galileo from its previous version? Particularly for Java programming.

Comment: I must admit I find the eclipse website a pain to navigate. Everything is hidden away!

Comment: why downvoted? good question - to me this is a valid question and there are helpful answers, +1.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Open the Welcome Page (Help -> Welcome) and click the icon labeled "What's New" (a yellow star).

Comment: Check out my article for some less obvious features: http://blog.zvikico.com/2009/07/eclipse-35-hidden-treasures.html

Answer (score 4):

You can have a look of the main new features [here](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.6M1-200908061400/eclipse-news-M1.html).

Answer (score 2):

See this page: [Eclipse 3.5 - New and Noteworthy](http://update.eclipse.org/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/eclipse-news-all.html) in particular the section on [new features for Java developers](http://update.eclipse.org/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/eclipse-news-all.html#JDT)

Answer (score 2):

Did you check out the press release? The new/updated features seem to be mentioned here:
http://www.eclipse.org/org/press-release/20090624_galileo.php

Answer (score 2):

Two things I like:

1) Generate toString()
2) Block Selection Mode